# tkinter update main dialog widgets from function

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm just getting started with tkinter, so the answer to this question may be rather obvious to those with more experience... My Python program defines a root window in the main code, which includes several label widgets:

```
for i in range(0,20):
    line.append(ttk.Label(mainframe, text=""))
    line[i].grid(column=1, row=i, sticky=W)
```

It also has a few menu items, one of which launches a graphical subprogram that operates in its own (pygame) window. I would like to modify the labels in the main window based on events in the subprogram, which I try using:

```
line[i].configure(text=s)
```

Problem is, these new label values don't show up until the subprogram completes and control returns to the main window. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Yes the way around is called multi-threading. In python you can for example use the threading module. If you start a function in a seperate thread the operating system will run both your gui and the function seemingly simultaneously.

Comment: OK, I'll have to look into that. Thanks for your response.